# using .scss file instead of css file in react

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, sass

in my project I am using `.sccs` file for css. now I have one strange issue. I have one browser extension which is coming over the input component. its `image id` is static so i need to hide it.
[image]

when I inspected it, below is coming.

[image]

in my `.scss` file I wrote below code.

```
  #__lpform_react-select-3-input_icon{
    visibility: hidden;
    display: none;
  }
```

its not working at all. then I created one additional `.css` file and just imported it and it is working perfectly fine.
if I write in below in my `.scss` file ,it hides all the `image` including this one. I need to get rid of only this image.

```
img{
visiblity:hidden ;
}
```

is there anything in addtion I need to do in my `scss` file so that it works? because architect is not allowing me to create additional `.css` file and asked me to put my changes in my .`scss` file.

my question is why it is working in `css` file and not in `scss` file. what additional step I need to do? could you please help me with that?

Answer (score 1):

For React you need to install the sass library.

Installation:

`npm i sass`

Create your sass file.

ex:

`my-file.scss`

Import the sass file in your javascript file.

ex:

`import './my-file.scss';`

Comment: thank you. sass file is already there and it is working for other component. can you guide how to hide that image icon please?

Answer (score 0):

React packages all your `scss` into one file and scopes them in the `root` element, so they don't work for elements outside the `root` element. If you want to hide the img using styles, you'd have to write those styles in a `style` tag in your `public/index.html` file.

```html
<!-- public/index.html -->

<body>
 <div id="root"></div>

 <!-- add this here -->
 <style>
  #__lpform_react-select-3-input_icon{
    visibility: hidden;
    display: none;
  }
 </style>
 
</body>
```

**OR**

You could use the dreaded `document.getElementById("#__lpform_react-select-3-input_icon")` api; Now I know you're not supposed to use it in react projects, but since this element is generated - as you mentioned - through an extension, react has no control over it, so there is no actual way react can access that element. Thus I think the use of `document.getElementById()` is justified in this case.