# image is coming over input element in react js

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, user-interface

when I launch the page, the browser extension icon(marked in red) is static and it is at the beginning.

[image]

when I type it keeps moving and covers the last typed text.

[image]

is there any `css` property through which I can prevent it coming on my component. I alredy tried

```
  input{
     background:none !important
     background-image:none !important
  }
```

but its not working.

I am using `react` and `.scss` file for css. this issue is not in other elements or components.

Comment: please add more details, best would be a working version of your issue in your code

Comment: Hey , you can just remove that image .

Comment: Can you create a sandbox that shows the error ,

Comment: You can just disable or remove the browser extension.

Comment: thank you. I put more details here. same question it is. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71448220/using-scss-file-instead-of-css-file-in-react/71449367#71449367